Is there a way to add custom build finished sound on Ubuntu 20 and Android Studio Iguana?
Do you know any plugin or way in Android Studio to enable sound after build finishes?
I want to add behaviour on IDE level, not to add it into project files like build.gradle.
I found that there are some ways on macOS to add custom sound for gradle notification in AS, but it does not show me the option to add custom sound.
Thanks in advance
